# dotnet publish sets Assembly path in temp directory instead of exe directory

Tags: c#, .net, publish

I build a dotnet 3.1 application that needs a configuration file (appSettings.json) in its running directory.

With a simple build, it behaves well, all these paths correspond to the directory where the executable is:

- `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`
- `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location)`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
- Goes to C:\repos\MyApp\bin\Release\MyApp.exe

Once published with `dotnet publish`, the previous paths goes to :

- C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp.net\MyApp\vbsjwe3q.y2w\MyApp.exe

Instead of the directory where the app is launched : C:\repos\MyApp\bin\Release\win-x86\publish

Is there a way to keep / retrieve the right path with a published app?
By "right", I mean the directory where the executable is deployed and not a temp directory.

Heres is my publish command:

> dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x86 --self-contained false -p:PublishReadyToRun=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true MyApp.csproj

Comment: @Sinatr NO, I explained the difference of behaviour between a simple build and a publication

Comment: are you publishing single file?

Comment: @FahimAbrar YES, it's in the dotnet publish parameters

Comment: take a look if that helps https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3885

Comment: @FahimAbrar I see I'm meant to set a DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR environment variable but I don't know how or when. If put my app into an installer, then the install directory can change so I can't guess it...

Comment: let's do rest in a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227897/discussion-between-sinsedrix-and-fahim-abrar).